# Negative conditions in if statements

Tags: c, if-statement

In theory this should work well but every time I type in `-1001` or `-3000`, it continues to run as though it passed through it perfectly met the conditions and the numbers add up. I do not know what else to try.

```
if((-1000 <= A, A<= 1000) &&(-1000 <= B, B <= 1000)){
```

Comment: You're already using `&&`, so keep using it.

Comment: No theory has ever supported that situation in C that I know. C does not work with conditions that way, and never has, the condition should probably be: `if((-1000 <= A && A <= 1000) && (-1000 <= B && B <= 1000))`, depending upon the goal.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't work the way you expect.

> ```
> if((-1000 <= A, A<= 1000) &&(-1000 <= B, B <= 1000)){
> ```

`(-1000 <= A, A<= 1000)` evaluates both expressions, but as a whole, evaluates only to the value of `A<= 1000`.  Both `-1000 <= A` and `-1000 <= B` can be false, and if the other expressions evaluate as true, the entire expression will be true.

If warnings are enabled in your compiler, it should warn you about the values of the expressions `-1000 <= A` and `-1000 <= B` being unused.

You likely wanted:

```
if ((-1000 <= A && A <= 1000) && (-1000 <= B && B <= 1000)) {
```

Or just:

```
if (-1000 <= A && A <= 1000 && -1000 <= B && B <= 1000) {
```

Though it's a matter of opinion, I don't like having to switch mental gears to compare numbers with variables this way. I'd rather:

```
if (A >= -1000 && A <= 1000 && B >= -1000 && B <= 1000) {
```

Of course, you could also write a function to handle this.

```
int in_range(int val, int start, int end) {
    return val >= start && val <= end;
}
```

And then:

```
if (in_range(A, -1000, 1000) && in_range(B, -1000, 1000)) {
```

Comment: And the function might well be defined as `static inline int in_range(int val, int start, int end) { return val >= start && val <= end; }`

Comment: Certainly agree with the "don't like having to switch mental gears to compare numbers with variables" - but to each their own.